# Run ARM-library on x86-based AVD with houdini (Android Emulator)

Tags: android, android-emulator, x86, arm, genymotion

I have a compiled library for ARM. I don't have access to the source code. I want to use this library in my own app. The app should run on an x86-based AVD (for performance reasons).

The problem is, I can't figure out how to run this ARM library on an x86-environment using houdini. I downloaded the houdini-libs and copied them over to `/system/lib/` resp. to `/system/lib/arm/` and tried to run my apk.

I tried three different approaches, but all failed:

1. If I copy the ARM-library to `/lib/armeabi/` and compile it with the gradle-flag

   ```
   splits {
       abi {
           enable true
           reset()
           include 'x86', 'armeabi'
           universalApk true
       }
   }
   ```

   the installation of the universal-apk fails with `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]`.
2. If I copy the ARM-library to `/lib/armeabi/` and compile it with `universalApk false` the lib isn't present in the resulting x86-apk. The library call fails with `... couldn't find "libXYZ.so"` (that's obvious, because it isn't present).
3. If I copy the ARM-library to `/lib/x86/` the library call fails with `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.jni.example/lib/x86/libXYZ.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40`. The machine-code 40 is ARM (and that's just right, the library is indeed ARM), but I don't get why this isn't translated by houdini.

Is there any way to run an ARM-library on an x86-emulator? How to set up houdini?

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:

I tried to use the personal version of Genymotion and flashed the houdini-library from this thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Everything worked fine, the problem is the library call now fails with a new error:

```
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.jni.example-1/libXYZ.so 0xa4df6228
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x3d6d at 0x10 in Lio/netty/util/internal/logging/Log4JLogger;.debug
D/houdini: [1481] Loading library(version: 3.2.1.43093 RELEASE)... successfully.
D/houdini: [1481] Open Native Library /data/app-lib/com.jni.example-1/libXYZ.so failed.
E/dalvikvm: dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.jni.example-1/libXYZ.so") failed: dlopen failed: "/data/app-lib/com.jni.example-1/libXYZ.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app-lib/com.jni.example-1/libXYZ.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

For Genymotion you can download the flashable houdini-library from here https://mega.nz/#!p4lFlCZR!TFsb8dMqNdAJjKoCDPDDvNtcQdEB0-KkVlTgQVwG20s and all the App with ARM architure library works smoothly.

Credit to 23pin who fixed & posted online: http://23pin.logdown.com/posts/691046-genymotion-use-arm-translation-on-6x-image

Comment: I managed to get my hands on a native x86-version of the library. But maybe someone else can profit from your link to houdini. Thanks!